# WPF data binding of a Ribbon control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ribbon

I have a working dynamic menu which is data bound to a hierarchical collection of items which are controlled by application dynamically. For reference below is WPF declaration:

```
        <Menu Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=dynamicMenu}">
       <Menu.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wm:AppAction}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding IsCheckable}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={wc:BoolToCollapsedConverter}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Image}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                            <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="False"/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.Resources>
    </Menu>
```

Now I would like to render this underlying menu structure using a Microsoft Ribbon control, initially structuring it using RibbonTab and RibbonGroup for level 0 and RibbonButton for level 1 (single group on each tab).

Unfortunately for some reason it does not show anything. Here is the declaration of what I've come with so far:

```
        <r:Ribbon Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="ribbon" Title="WPF Prototype App" ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}">
        <r:Ribbon.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wm:AppAction}">
                <r:RibbonTab Header="{Binding Text}">
                    <r:RibbonGroup Header="{Binding Text}" ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" Width="333">
                        <r:RibbonGroup.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wm:AppAction}">
                                <r:RibbonButton Label="{Binding Text}" LargeImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </r:RibbonGroup.Resources>
                    </r:RibbonGroup>
                </r:RibbonTab>
            </DataTemplate>
        </r:Ribbon.Resources>
    </r:Ribbon>
```

I have a feeling this might be something simple to solve.
I tried using HierarchicalDataTemplate but there were errors about style for RibbonTab being applied to RibbonGroup.

Another related question would be: if AppAction object had a ribbon control style discriminator property (i.e. ControlStyle [Tab, Group, Button, CheckBox, ComboBox]), how easy would be to dynamically create appropriate control depending on the value of this property or is it even possible ? Or is it better for complex scenarios to just define parts of a ribbon in subsequent Views responsible for these tasks and just attach them when View is visible ?

Edit: Below are the contents of a simplified version of AppAction class:

```
    [ContentProperty("Items")]
public class AppAction: PropertyChangedBase
{
    public AppActionCollection Items { get; set; }

    ICommand command;
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return command; }
        set { CheckSet(ref command, value); }
    }

    string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { CheckSet(ref text, value); }
    }

    Uri imageSource;
    public Uri ImageSource
    {
        get { return imageSource; }
        set { image = null; CheckSet(ref imageSource, value); NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Image); }
    }

    public AppAction()
    {
        Items = new AppActionCollection();
    }
}
```

AppActionCollection simplified:

```
public class AppActionCollection: ObservableCollection<AppAction>
{
}
```

An example menu tree can be created by:

```
public class TestMenu
{
    AppActionCollection menu = new AppActionCollection();

    public TestMenu()
    {
        var m = new AppAction { Text = "File" };
        m.Items.Add(new AppAction { Text = "Open" });
        m.Items.Add(new AppAction { Text = "Save" });
        m.Items.Add(new AppAction { Text = "" });
        m.Items.Add(new AppAction { Text = "Exit", Command = ApplicationCommands.Close });
        menu.Add(m);

        m = new AppAction { Text = "Edit" };
        m.Items.Add(new AppAction { Text = "Copy" });
        m.Items.Add(new AppAction { Text = "Paste" });
        m.Items.Add(new AppAction { Text = "Cut" });
        m.Items.Add(new AppAction { Text = "Smile", Command = ApplicationCommands.Close });
        menu.Add(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using `Resources` and `DataTemplate` ? what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm using resources because supposedly HierarchicalDataTemplate won't work with nested levels without using Resources. After working by analogy Resources are a left-over. Second snippet does not work (yet).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry for delay, i was looking for solution to your problem, but unfortunately i didn't find.
`HierarchicalDataTemplate` does't help you because the ribbon levels are not of the same type.

I think that the only way to solve your problem is to make new `DataTemplate` for each level. i know that this is not good solution, but i think that this is the only way.
if you find better way please share your knowledge and tell me.

Note: in `Menu` situation you can use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` because there is one Type `MenuItem`.

**Edit:**

this what i reached to:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public ObservableCollection<AppAction> child
{
    get
    {
        ObservableCollection<AppAction> reVal = new ObservableCollection<AppAction>();
        reVal.Add(
            new AppAction() { Header = "File", Items = new ObservableCollection<AppAction>() { 
                new AppAction() { Header = "Font", Items = new ObservableCollection<AppAction>() { 
                    new AppAction() { Header = "Arial" }, 
                    new AppAction() { Header = "Segoe UI" }, 
                    new AppAction() { Header = "Tahoma" } } }, 
                new AppAction() { Header = "Other", Items = new ObservableCollection<AppAction>() { 
                    new AppAction() { Header = "Colse" } } } } });

        reVal.Add(
            new AppAction() { Header = "View", Items = new ObservableCollection<AppAction>() { 
                new AppAction() { Header = "A", Items = new ObservableCollection<AppAction>() { 
                    new AppAction() { Header = "AButton" } } }, 
                new AppAction() { Header = "B", Items = new ObservableCollection<AppAction>() { 
                    new AppAction() { Header = "BButton" } } }, 
                new AppAction() { Header = "C", Items = new ObservableCollection<AppAction>() { 
                    new AppAction() { Header = "CButton" } } } } });
        return reVal;
    }
}
```

and in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="rebbon.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="wind">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="buttonTempl">
            <RibbonButton Label="{Binding Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="RibbonGroup" x:Key="groupStyle">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource buttonTempl}"/>
        </Style>        
        <Style TargetType="RibbonTab" x:Key="tabStyle">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource groupStyle}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Ribbon ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource tabStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=wind, Path=child}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Result:**

[image]

I hope that this will help you.

I did my best.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, your example uses a single object ("MyDate") to which ribbon is bound to. I have a nested tree of objects of type "AppAction", each having Items property with (possibly) more child AppAction objects and levels of nested items should be bound to RibbonTab, RibbonGroup and RibbonButton.

Comment: could you please edit your question to add you class logic and window behind code, i really don't understand if you have list of class or one object.

Comment: Big thanks for the solution, it solves the problem in a very neat way.

Comment: @MoHaKa, you answer also solve my problem. Do you know why [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43876622/wpf-ribbon-binding-tabs-groups-and-buttons-dynamically-using-mvvm) does not work?